# Will Changing URL aliases of Drupal 6 site affect Google Analytics statistics?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, seo, google-analytics

If I change the URL aliases for a Drupal 6 site, will Google Analytics data be affected?

For instance, if node A is changed from http://www.example.com/path-a to http://www.example.com/path-b, will GA Page Views data be reset?

Is GA intelligent enough to treat these pages as one and the same or will I need to set up a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA will take these 2 paths as 2 pages. However when you change paths, always try to add a redirect. 
Page redirect module(D6. Redirects in D7) can add redirects automatically when path-auto pattern changes.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics data does not adjust itself retroactively, and is blind to "true" configuration settings.

If you send a URL as `/path-a`, and then change it to `/path-b`, Google Analytics will assume that they are totally separate URLs.